# Python: reading '\xc2' from file prints fine but printing string variable with same value fails

Tags: python

```
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
```

`path` is file with single line as `\xc2`

when I run this I get

`\xc2`

now lets change this

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
                var = '\xc2'
                print var
```

When I run this, I see

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii', '\xc2d', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)'
```

then I try to compare the so I do

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line1 = '\xc2d'
        # print line1
        print line == line1
```

and I see `False`

What is happening here??

Comment: You want a raw string.  `'\xc2d'` is being escaped, so it looks like what you want is `r'\xc2d'`, or `'\\xc2d'`

Comment: @JoelCornett, it's actually being interpreted as character code 0xc2 (not Unicode) followed by `d`. `len('\xc2d')` returns 2.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Oops you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read characters from a file, `\` is just another character and has no special meaning. When you try to create a string from it though, it's used as an escape that has special meanings depending on what follows. For example `\x` means take the next 2 hex digits and create the character that corresponds to the hex code, thus `'\xc2'` is a single character. Since this character code isn't in the ASCII range of 0 to 127 (0x7f), you get an error when you try to print it.